# OSX with RVM "cannot load such file -- bridgesupportparser (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, rubymotion

I hit this problem running rake on a RubyMotion project, but it feels like it's a more general RVM-on-Mac issue.

I'm running rvm 2.3.1 on OSX 10.11.6

If I fire up irb and try require 'bridgesupportparser' I get the error

> cannot load such file -- bridgesupportparser (LoadError)

I can find the .rb file at

> /System/Library/BridgeSupport/ruby-2.0/bridgesupportparser.rb

And if I do

> require '/System/Library/BridgeSupport/ruby-2.0/bridgesupportparser'',

I get a new error, which is

> 'cannot load such file -- bridgesupportparser.so'

It looks like I need bridgesupportparser.so and bridgesupportparser.rb to be somewhere ruby can find them.

I have several bridgesupportparser.rb files on my machine, but no bridgesupportparser.so. There are bridgesupportparser.bundle files, though - looks like they may be the Mac version of the .so files.

As I first ran into it with RubyMotion, I did the following:

- New install of Xcode (8.0)
- Deleted and reinstalled RubyMotion (4.13)
- Tried this (suggested [here](http://community.rubymotion.com/t/rake-aborted-using-rm4/920/3)):

> mv /Library/RubyMotion/lib/BridgeSupport mv
>   /Library/RubyMotion/lib/BridgeSupport.bak

- rake newclear

But none of that has fixed the issue. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to re-install the xcode-cli tools?  $ xcode-select --install

Comment: Good question: thank you. Yes, I did that already, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Upgraded to OSX 10.12 (Sierra). Now it works. Go figure!